# How to compare two maps and retrieve key of the value that occurs in both maps?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
newPropertiesFile.keySet().parallelStream()
    .filter(value -> oldPropertiesFile.keySet().parallelStream()
            .filter(entry -> oldPropertiesFile.get(entry).toString().equals(newPropertiesFile.get(value).toString()))
            .filter(values -> !values.equals(value)).count() > 0)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(entryKey -> (String) entryKey, entryKey -> newPropertiesFile.get(entryKey).toString()));
```

For Example,
I have `mapA = {(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c')}` and `mapB = {(5,'a'),(6,'d'),(7,'c')}`
Comparing the valueList of both the maps, the values `'a'` and `'c'` in `mapA` occur in `mapB` and their keys are `5` and `7` resp.

And hence my required o/p:
`5`, `7`

I have done the above and got my required output. But the Complexity is too damn high on O(n^2). Any optimized methods?

A more Simplified example:

```
mapA.keySet().parallelStream()
    .filter(v->mapB.keySet().parallelStream()
            .filter(e->mapB.get(v).equals(mapA.get(v)))
            .filter(v->!v.equals(v)).count()>0)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: how about a simplified example we could digest?

Comment: it might be simple for you since you have a lot of context - me reading this, is an entire different story

Comment: this code is a huge mess, `entry` when that is _really_ a `Key`; equality based on `toString` (is this ever a good idea?); I can only _assume_ that the value is really a `List<Something>`; `filter.count()` can be replaced with `anyMatch`, etc. Voting to close until you explain in pure English what you are trying to do

Comment: I feel the OP wants this: Has 2 maps A and B and wants to find out the keys of a particular value in both the maps. He is already doing traversing the second map B for every value of A and check if B has that value. He wants a lesser costing operation.

Comment: Sorry but I am very new to the coding world. I have two maps. I want to check whether a value `v` in `map1` is present in `map2`'s value list and if present, retrieve the key `k` of the value `v` in `map2`.

Comment: it's fine if you are knew - no worries. but you could say I have a `Map` that looks like `A= [1, 2,3]` and a second Map `B = [4,5,6]`; I would like to obtain the following output... here is what I tried.

Comment: @Eugene I have edited the question as per your Guidelines :)

Comment: If you are fine with modifying `mapB`, you can use `mapB.values().retainAll(mapA.values());`, then `mapB.keySet()` contains the keys you are interested in. You can also make a copy when you want to avoid modifying `mapB`: `Map<…> result = new HashMap<>(mapB); result.values().retainAll(mapA.values()); System.out.println(result.keySet());` If `mapA` is really large, it may pay off to use `result.values().retainAll(new HashSet<>(mapA.values()));`

Comment: @Holger Nice; you should post this as an answer. The `retainAll` method calls `contains` repeatedly on its argument, so copying mapA's values into a `HashSet` reduces a linear search to a constant time search. This is essential for avoiding the O(n^2) growth that the OP wants to avoid. I'm not sure what qualifies as "really large", but my informal measurements show that the O(n^2) performance starts to become noticeable at a only few thousand map entries.

Comment: Yes, @StuartMarks my map contains more than 15000 entries, so n^2 take a much longer time

Comment: @StuartMarks it’s the same “large” that is used to explain that the Big O notation only tells you how the performance scales with large numbers. Generally, I’d answer that question with a counter question: *do you know the maximum number, your program will ever process?* If no, then it’s potentially large and should treat the input as large. If yes, just test whether the performance is good enough or which variant performs better for that maximum sample input. Though, there’s nothing wrong with always treating the input as large.

Comment: @Holger Yes, I was assuming that the OP was concerned about the O(N^2) growth because the map had enough entries that it was causing a problem. Indeed, above he mentions 15,000 entries. This is large enough to make a difference between milliseconds and minutes on my machine. Then again, OP accepted an answer that exhibits O(N^2) growth, so go figure....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's summarize some of the variations on this, as the best solution only emerges after reading the other answer and the comments.

The simplified problem from the question is something like this. Given two maps:

```
Map<Integer, String> mapA = Map.of(1, "a", 2, "b", 3, "c")
Map<Integer, String> mapB = Map.of(5, "a", 6, "d", 7, "c")
```

find the keys of `mapB` that correspond to values that occur in both maps. The question had a start at a solution which was this (edited for clarity):

```
Set<Integer> result = mapB.keySet().stream()
    .filter(keyB -> mapA.keySet().stream()
                        .filter(keyA -> mapA.get(keyA).equals(mapB.get(keyB)))
                        .count() > 0)
    .collect(toSet());
```

Essentially this is like two nested loops that loop over the keys of each map. The inner loop gets the corresponding values for each key and counts the number of matches. If there's at least one match, key gets passed through the filter to the result.

The OP wasn't satisified with this and requested improvements, particularly about algorithmic complexity. As mentioned in the comments, the real problem might have 15,000 map entries. This algorithm is O(n^2), and it does begin to degrade noticeably with this number of mappings. There are some minor ways this could be improved, such as by using `anyMatch` instead of `filter` and `count > 0`, but these aren't necessary given the alternative proposed in the [answer from Eritrean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56836907/1441122):

```
Set<Integer> result = mapB.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> mapA.values().contains(entry.getValue()))
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .collect(toSet());
```

This is nicer, as it uses the `contains` operation on mapA's `values()` view, replacing the inner stream of the previous solution. However, the values of a map aren't indexed, and so the only way that `contains()` over the values of a map can work is (potentially) to search every entry. This is somewhat better than before in that if a match is found, `contains()` can return immediately; but if a match isn't found, it must search all the values of the map. Therefore, on average, this variation still runs in O(n^2) time.

One way to mitigate this is to pull mapA's values into a `HashSet`. This will reduce the `contains()` check from linear time to constant time, reducing the overall complexity from O(n^2) to O(n). That would look like this:

```
Set<String> aValues = new HashSet<>(mapA.values());
Set<Integer> result = mapB.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> aValues.contains(entry.getValue()))
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .collect(toSet());
```

This is a big improvement, but it turns out that using streams isn't necessary at all. Returning to the problem statement, it has the clause "... values that occur in both maps." This is essentially doing a set intersection on the values collections. The way to do intersection in Java is with the `retainAll` method. That is, given two collections `x` and `y`, doing `x.retainAll(y)` will retain in `x` only those elements that also occur in `y`, and it will remove others. That's essentially a set intersection. To do this, `retainAll` typically must call `contains` repeatedly on `y`, so it's a good idea to make sure that operation is fast -- like with a `HashSet`.

OK, if we intersect the values collections, that gives us values -- but we want the keys. In particular, we want the keys of mapB. How do we do that?

It turns out that the `values()` view of a map supports removal -- which `retainAll` does -- and if a value is removed from it, that removes the corresponding entry from the underlying map. In this case we can start with mapB (or a copy), get its `values()` view, call `retainAll` with mapA's values that we had previously loaded into a `HashSet`. That leaves in mapB only the entries that have values in common with mapA. Since we're interested in the keys, not the entries, we just get the `keySet()` view. That code looks like this:

```
Set<String> aValues = new HashSet<>(mapA.values());
Map<Integer, String> mapBcopy = new HashMap<>(mapB);
mapBcopy.values().retainAll(aValues);
Set<Integer> result = mapBcopy.keySet();
```

This demonstrates how it's possible to use collections bulk operations on collection views to accomplish certain tasks more simply than using streams.

Comment: Excellent answer! I was glad to see this referenced in [your presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lj1fvPhp1dM) the other day.

Comment: your last snippets should really be : `Map<Integer, String> mapBcopy = new HashMap<>(mapB);` and `mapBcopy.values().retainAll(aValues);` (slight variables names and types are wrong)

Comment: @Eugene Indeed, fixed. I usually compile my answers before posting them, and look what happens when I don't! Thanks for pointing out the errors.

Comment: @StuartMarks no big deal, this is a better place to be because you are here. Thank you.